# c++ непонятное обнуление аргумента функции

Tags: c++, winapi

Мне нужно, чтобы программу в указанной директории все файлы складывала в одноименные директории. В каждой папке может быть сколько угодно файлов с разными расширениями.
У меня есть функция, которая перемещает файл в субдиректорию (Автоматически создает папку) с таким же именем, только с обрезанным расширением, вот собственно код:
`(Working path = C:\\TestPath, filename = C:\\TestPath\\dasdas.txt, to = dasdas)`

```
void move_filename_to (const TCHAR* filename, const TCHAR* to) {

    const unsigned int s = sizeof(working_path) + sizeof(TEXT("\\")) + sizeof(to) + 1;
    TCHAR directory[s] = "";
    _tcscpy(directory, working_path);
    _tcscat(directory, TEXT("\\"));
    _tcscat(directory, to);
    directory[s] = '\0';

    //Лично здесь, все в порядке и создается директория (C:\TestPath\dasdas)
    //directory = C:\\TestPath\\dasdas

    _mkdir(directory);
    printf("\tSubdirectory %s created\n", directory);


    const unsigned int old_size = sizeof(working_path) + sizeof(TEXT("\\")) + sizeof(filename) + 1;
    TCHAR old_path[old_size] = "";
    _tcscpy(old_path, working_path);
    _tcscat(old_path, TEXT("\\"));
    _tcscat(old_path, filename);
    old_path[old_size] = '\0';

    //Здесь тоже все отлично 
    //old_path = C:\\TestPath\\dasdas.txt

    const unsigned int new_size = sizeof(working_path) + sizeof(TEXT("\\")) + sizeof(TEXT("\\")) + sizeof(to) + sizeof(filename) + 1;
    TCHAR new_path[new_size] = {0,}; //На этой строчке to = dasdas
    _tcscpy(new_path, working_path); //А тут она уже становится нулевой :(
    _tcscat(new_path, TEXT("\\"));
    _tcscat(new_path, to);
    _tcscat(new_path, TEXT("\\"));
    _tcscat(new_path, filename);
    new_path[new_size] = '\0';

    printf("Moving from %s to %s\n", old_path, directory);

    printf("DEBUG: \n\t\told_path = %s\n\t\tnew_path = %s\n\t\tdirectory = %s", old_path, new_path, directory);

    int status = rename(old_path, new_path);

    printf("\t\tMoving ");
    if (status == 0)
        printf(" OK\n");
    else printf(" failed\n");


    delete[] directory;
    delete[] old_path;
    delete[] new_path;
}
```

Почему пропадает `to`?

[image: to еще существует]
[image: to занулилась]

Comment: Может стоит добавить немного `c++` ?

Comment: Не путайте `sizeof` и кол-во символов. В случае `TCHAR` разница может быть в два раза

Comment: `delete []` в конце тоже не понял. Зачем Вы его туда добавили?

Comment: И вообще - старайтесь использовать защищенные версии функций работы со строками с суффиксом `_s` (например, `_tcscpy_s`)

Comment: @gecube более того, sizeof(to) вернет размер указателя, а не строки.

Comment: И что же делать?

Comment: @gecube не нужно очищать память?

Comment: @vladimir понимаю, выглядит как сишный, а что делать, если юникод только в tchar и в wstring. Причем приведение типов меня пугает.

Comment: @Herrgott а че wstring не подошел?

Comment: @Herrgott разберитесь чем выделение на стеке и в куче отличается. И про разные способы выделения памяти : `malloc`, `new` и `new []`

Comment: Ну и пахарошему наверное лучше std::filesystem::u8path например (если кампиллер позволяет).

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian по-хорошему автору вопроса нужно уточнить что у него за задача. TCHAR это не плохо, и не хорошо, но на них МОЖНО собрать эффективный код работы с WinAPI. Но у std::wstring есть существенное преимущество - сложнее напороть косяки из-за выделения памяти и детских ошибок вроде выхода за пределы массива

Comment: @vladimir wstring я читал не очень юникод может

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы программу в указанной директории все файлы складывала в одноименные директории. В каждой папке может быть сколько угодно файлов с разными расширениями

Comment: А вот ещё интересный момент, имена файлов вы где получаете, которые на вход этой функции попадают?

Comment: @vladimir через dirent

Comment: Дичь. sizeof возвращает размер типа, а не длину строки. new_size должен быть известен на момент компиляции. TCHAR вперемешку с обычными char.